# Set background image and other properties of all forms

Tags: c#

I'd like to know how is it possible to set a background image for all my windows forms, also other properties such as disable controlbox, minimizebox, etc. I read from somewhere I could use inheritance, how is this possible? Should I create a base class with all these settings? So far I've just been able to import my image into the resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use inheritance, you can have a class and make all the Form classes inherit from the base one. Here's an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class BaseForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
        base.OnActivated(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I set the controlbox property as false and other properties such as minimizebox, maximize box?

Comment: Is it possible to also change the date format using this method? because some of my forms have datetime picker and i want to change their format into dd/MM/yyyy but if i place them inside the load, since this will override it, the format doesn't change

Comment: If you create another question about it I will be glad to answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Class as `MyForm` Inherited from `System.Windows.Forms`.
2. Apply Your All Properties to this MyForm
   then You can Use this `MyForm` in your all other Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and it has a name : visual inheritance. You can google that term and get a lot of useful information on how to do it.

You can start here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The idea is basically the same as with any other inheritance. So it is not difficult at all.